# Mysql with Group by + IF + Left Join + Group_Concat

Tags: mysql

I'm think its so trivial, but I stuck with this:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name,

IF(s.prod_id=0, 1,NULL) as amount,
IF(s.prod_id=92, 2,NULL) as amount2,
IF(s.prod_id=116, 3,NULL) as amount3,
IF(s.prod_id=134, 4,NULL) as amount4

FROM table_user u

LEFT JOIN table_user_status s ON s.user_id = u.id 
where s.prod_id = 0 OR s.prod_id = 92 OR s.prod_id = 117 OR s.prod_id = 134

-- GROUP BY u.id
order by u.id ASC
```

I get something like:

```
22 | Matt | 1|NULL|NULL|NULL

22 | Matt | NULL|2|NULL|NULL
```

After Group by id I get `22 MATT 1 NULL NULL NULL` and then next record.

At the end i must user group_concat for data like
`22 | Matt | 1,2 |`

Thanks!

Comment: You have 116 in the SELECT and 117 in the WHERE. I guess one is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression to return all those cases as a single column then just `GROUP_CONCAT` it:

```
SELECT
    u.id,
    u.name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(amount ORDER BY amount) amounts
FROM
(
    SELECT
        u.id,
        u.name,
        CASE s.prod_id
            WHEN 0   THEN 1
            WHEN 92  THEN 2
            WHEN 116 THEN 3
            WHEN 134 THEN 4
        END AS amount
    FROM table_user u
    LEFT JOIN table_user_status s
        ON s.user_id = u.id 
    WHERE s.prod_id IN (0, 92, 116, 134)
) u
GROUP BY
    u.id,
    u.name
ORDER BY u.id
```

Comment: Nice catch.  My updated query had a smell, and getting everything into a single column is definitely the way to go here +1.

Comment: Wow, you are big bro! I appreciate it, thank you so much! Im sad that i can't give you "up". :(

Comment: Don't worry, I'm never gonna let you down.

Comment: Rick Roll'd even here :D